# What are the ethics of having a company "sponsor" a loco team event?

Tags: community, locoteams

I've got a LoCo event coming up, and a local company (that uses and loves Ubuntu) has approached me (since I'm the organizer) with the following proposal:

They'd like to "sponsor" the event - bring in coffee (as well as providing us with a meeting place) in exchange for a nice little blurb - is that considered "OK" to do?

Are there guidelines for this sorta thing already? Or do I have to use my gut to make sure it doesn't become "commercial"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an Ubuntu member, I don't see anything wrong with this in the least. Especially if the sponsor "uses and loves Ubuntu." There's precedent for this as well. Just off the top of my head, I know that the UK LoCo Team's podcast has [sponsorship](http://podcast.ubuntu-uk.org/sponsors/). System 76 and ZaReason have both been know to sponsor LoCo events as well. I don't believe there are any guidelines, but if in doubt about a specific situation, contact the LoCo Council: `loco-council<at>lists.ubuntu.com`

Answer (score 6):

I don't see anything wrong with this at all! It already happens in other LoCos. You're approaching it with the right mentality though. The benefit (of funding, etc) to the event attendees should heavily outweigh the marketing presence. A visible logo and a mention at the beginning and end seems like a typical convention, erm, convention.

If they want to sit everybody down and give them a 10 minute talk, that's probably too far... Unless they're going to give everybody an ice cream and a cigar... There's always a balance to be made, I guess.

I've had a rummage around for official guidelines but haven't found anything but as Andrew says, there are mailing lists for this sort of support.

Comment: I win! (for viral nature).

Answer (score 2):

Per discussions I have had with a LoCo Council Member there is no problem accepting sponsorship's or donations from companies so long as such a sponsorship or donation does not come with strings attached that require the LoCo to do sales pitches or endorse a certain product or company.

Further I have talked with a few other LoCo Team Leads and it seems like accepting sponsorship's and donations is common and helps LoCo's provide common things like stickers, shirts and light food at events.

I guess a good rule of thumb is just try to make it clear that by making a donation or sponsoring an event that they are not entitled to any endorsement or perk other than perhaps a personal thanks at the event or once on the mailing list. Additionally I personally feel that when accepting donations or sponsorship's it is best to be transparent to your entire LoCo and make sure the entire team knows what was donated/sponsored.

In closing I suggest if a company is going to sponsor an expense that you ask that they directly pay for it versus accepting any monies.

Surely, if you have any questions or need guidance you can always seek out such from the LoCo Council via their mailing list or on IRC.